# yum update glibc - ERROR with rpm_check_debug vs depsolve:

Tags: centos, yum, rpm, upgrade, glibc

I want to update my system with `yum update` but I get only errors starting with these two lines:

```
Running rpm_check_debug
ERROR with rpm_check_debug vs depsolve:
```

Then, I tried only to update the library `glibc` with `yum update glibc`. The result was:

```
Running rpm_check_debug
ERROR with rpm_check_debug vs depsolve:
libc.so.6()(64bit) is needed by libattr-2.4.44-7.el6.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by libattr-2.4.44-7.el6.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit) is needed by libattr-2.4.44-7.el6.x86_64
libc.so.6()(64bit) is needed by libcap-2.16-5.5.el6.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by libcap-2.16-5.5.el6.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit) is needed by libcap-2.16-5.5.el6.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.3)(64bit) is needed by libcap-2.16-5.5.el6.x86_64
libc.so.6()(64bit) is needed by glibc-common-2.12-1.166.el6_7.7.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.10)(64bit) is needed by glibc-common-2.12- 1.166.el6_7.7.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by glibc-common-2.12-1.166.el6_7.7.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit) is needed by glibc-common-2.12-1.166.el6_7.7.x86_64
libdl.so.2()(64bit) is needed by glibc-common-2.12-1.166.el6_7.7.x86_64
libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by glibc-common-2.12-1.166.el6_7.7.x86_64
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

**What I tried so far?**

1) `yum clean all` or `yum clean dbcache`, but both of them did not work.

2) `rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest` also no result

Are there any other solutions for that problem? Or possible ways?

I am working on `CentOS release 6.7 (Final)`

`yum repolist` gives me:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.datente.com
 * extras: mirror.netcologne.de
 * updates: mirror.netcologne.de
repo id                repo name                status
base                   CentOS-6 - Base           6,575
extras                 CentOS-6 - Extras            50
updates                CentOS-6 - Updates        1,453
repolist: 8,078
```